# Woman attacked in a toilet and forced to drink monsterising liquid through a funnel

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I remember watching this on TV but it might have been a film or a TV show.

A woman is stopping at a resting spot in a forest area. She goes to the bathroom (stalls, very dirty) and she got attacked by two masked guys. They force her to drink a watery substance contained in a transparent jar using a funnel.

I remember the liquid they were feeding the people with was to turn them into monsters(?).

Edit: More info:

- Was in color (released late 90's or 2000's probably).
- Probably from the US (north america for sure)
- Don't remember any name.
- Masked aggressors were wearing black hoods
- The woman arrives at the stop with a man (a couple ?). The man is attacked (same as the woman, first) and then they attack the woman.
- Can't remember what kind of monster they turn into (not even sure if this is even monster now. Maybe some kind of alien taking over people ?).

Comment: If you do remember anything else, please be sure to [edit] it in to your question. For some helpful pointers if you're stuck, take a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions/9337)

Comment: @Remar - I'm sure you can recall more. Was this in colour or black and white? What kind of monsters were they? Was the woman alone or with friends? What was her name? What was she driving or how did she get to the rest stop? What were the masks they were wearing? Did she say anything? What language was the film/episode in?

Comment: House of 1000 Corpses has a scene with a funnel. Not much else fits, but worth adding as a negative